# Tikz-Feynman: Putting multiple boson loops into each other

Tags: tikz-pgf, feynman, tikz-feynman

I was trying to draw a Feynman diagram of a quark propagator in rainbow ladder truncation when I encountered a problem.
I need to draw multiple gluon loops within each other. Drawing one gluon loop is no problem, but trying to put another one into that results in something that looks like

[image]

The problem are the last two diagrams in that equation. What I want is the diagrams to look somewhat like
[image]

Please, excuse my bad drawing. I hope you get, what I mean.
I produced the above result with the code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,automata,backgrounds,calc,er,patterns}
\tikzfeynmanset{compat=1.0.0}
\begin{document}
$\feynmandiagram[horizontal=a to b, tree layout]{
a-- [fermion] b;
};
\quad\raisebox{-0.5ex}{=}\quad
\feynmandiagram[horizontal=a to b, tree layout]{
a -- b;
};
\raisebox{-0.5ex}{+}
\feynmandiagram[horizontal=b to c, tree layout] {
b -- c,
b -- [gluon, half left] c;
};
\raisebox{-0.5ex}{+}
\feynmandiagram[horizontal=a to d, tree layout] {
a -- b -- c -- d,
b -- [gluon, half left] c,
a -- [gluon, half left] d;
};
\raisebox{-0.5ex}{+}
\feynmandiagram[horizontal=a to f, tree layout] {
a -- b -- c -- d -- e -- f,
c -- [gluon, half left] d,
b -- [gluon, half left] e,
a -- [gluon, half left] f;
};
\raisebox{-0.5ex}{+\dots}$
\end{document}
```

If I don't use "tree layout" attribute, the diagrams look like
[image]

which is still not what I want. Using version 1.1.0 instead of 1.0.0 does not change anything either.
The compiler I am using is LuaLatex.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your code gives you precisely what you wan (I think) if you compile with pdflatex.

Comment: It indeed does, thanks! The problem is that I have other diagrams in the same document, that do not compile properly using pdflatex but do fine with LuaLatex.
I worked around this by compiling this diagram in pdflatex and then putting it in the document as a graphic.

So I guess this topic is solved.

Comment: In principle you could work with `\diagram*` (see end of section 3.1 in the manual) which "uses the most basic algorithm".

Comment: I think it is advantageous to go the `\diagram*` route since this way global settings of the document (e.g. the line width of the propagators) will automatically apply to the diagram without the need of re-compiling the diagram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment I understand that you have several diagrams in your document that rely on lualatex. Therefore, I propose to use `\diagram*` (see end of section 3.1 in the manual) which "uses the most basic algorithm".

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,automata,backgrounds,calc,er,patterns}
\tikzfeynmanset{compat=1.0.0}
\begin{document}
$\tikz{\begin{feynman}\diagram*{
a-- [fermion] b;
};\end{feynman}}
\quad\raisebox{-0.5ex}{=}\quad
\tikz{\begin{feynman}\diagram*{
a -- b;
};\end{feynman}}
\raisebox{-0.5ex}{+}
\tikz{\begin{feynman}\diagram*{
b -- c,
b -- [gluon, half left] c;
};\end{feynman}}
\raisebox{-0.5ex}{+}
\tikz{\begin{feynman}\diagram*{
a -- b -- c -- d,
b -- [gluon, half left] c,
a -- [gluon, half left] d;
};\end{feynman}}
\raisebox{-0.5ex}{+}
\tikz{\begin{feynman}\diagram*{
a -- b -- c -- d -- e -- f,
c -- [gluon, half left] d,
b -- [gluon, half left] e,
a -- [gluon, half left] f;
};\end{feynman}}
\raisebox{-0.5ex}{+\dots}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

I know that you already went another way, but maybe this answer will be helpful for others who encounter similar problems in the future.

Comment: This works just fine, too. I implemented it this way now since it is more elegant. Thanks!